# Does quasi-isomorphic complexes of sheaves give the same cohomology groups?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

Let $F^{\bullet}$ and $ I^{\bullet }$ be two bounded below complexes of sheaves of $O_X$-modules (on a scheme X) and let $F^{\bullet}\rightarrow I^{\bullet}$ be a quasi-isomorphism between complexes of sheaves. Take the global section functor $\Gamma(X,)$ and take cohomology, is it true that $H^*(\Gamma(X,F^{\bullet}))\cong H^*(\Gamma(X,I^{\bullet}))$?

Comment: No. If it were then sheaf cohomology for ordinary sheaves would be trivial, right?

Comment: @ZhenLin what if $F^{\bullet}$ is flasque and $G$ is injective, does these condition helps

Comment: If $G^\bullet = I^\bullet$? Are the $I^k$ injective sheaves?

Comment: Bounded-below cochain complexes of injectives are K-injective, and quasi-isomorphisms between K-injective complexes are automatically homotopy equivalences hence preserved by any additive functor. But I am not sure whether complexes of flasque sheaves are K-injective.

Comment: @red_trumpet yes, and $G^k$ are flasque

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To flesh out Zhen Lin's initial comment, if $F$ is a sheaf of modules, and $I^\bullet$ is an injective resolution of $F$, then there is a quasi-isomorphism from the complex $F[0]=\cdots \to 0 \to F \to 0 \to \cdots$, and the injective resolution $I^\bullet$ (cf. [Stacks Project 013G](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/013G)). By definition, the $i$'th cohomology of the complex $\Gamma(X, I^\bullet)$ is $H^i(X, F)$. On the other hand, the $i$'th cohomology of $\Gamma(X, F[0])$ is trivial for $i > 0$.

As such, if what you said was true, all higher sheaf cohomology would be trivial.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me like the OP may not have meant to take global sections before taking cohomology: @Yuan Yang, did you really mean to take global sections *before* taking cohomology, or did you mean to take the right derived functor of global sections *as* cohomology? It seems to me like your original intended question was: "Given two quasi-isomorphic complexes, if we use global sections to compute sheaf cohomology, then will the resulting homology complexes be isomorphic?" And there the answer is **yes** if we are willing to take hypercohomology as the cohomology of a space with coefficients in given complex of sheaves because hypercohomology is a functor of derived categories.

That is, for two complexes $\mathcal{F}_1^\bullet \simeq_{qis} \mathcal{F}_2^\bullet$ which are quasi-isomorphic, then we have $\mathbb{H}^*(X, \mathcal{F}_1) \cong \mathbb{H}^*(X, \mathcal{F}_2^\bullet)$. See for instance Corollary 30 of Robert Friedman's notes on cohomology here: [https://www.math.columbia.edu/~rf/cohomology](https://www.math.columbia.edu/%7Erf/cohomology)